# How to change fields in bulk in mongodb?

Tags: database, mongodb

Suppose I have a collection `foo` like so:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("7a917971947913749")
    bar: 27
    other: "stuff1"
},

{
    _id: ObjectId("7a917971947913750")    
    bar: 28
    other: "stuff2"

}
```

where bar is an Integer. I want to apply a query to this collection such that the resulting collection's each item has its `bar` property multiplied by 100 like so:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("7a917971947913749")
    bar: 2700
    other: "stuff1"
},

{
    _id: ObjectId("7a917971947913750")    
    bar: 2800
    other: "stuff2"

}
```

What will that query be?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to overwrite existing field and [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) to replace your existing collection with aggregation output:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            bar: { $multiply: [ "$bar", 100 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "foo"
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an aggregation pipeline to calculate new documents for every input document where the new field `bar` = 100 * the previous value of that field.

See documentation for [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/), [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

It may be better to write the output into a new collection e.g. `foov2`.